# Pattern for conditionally fetching user data with useSWR, only when the user actually has credentials for the request (i.e an access/refresh token)

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, jwt, swr

so I have a react app with JWT authentication where the refresh token is stored in a httpOnly cookie, and the access token is stored in memory. I have made a hook for fetching user data that uses useSWR, and everything works (nearly) perfectly with axios as the fetcher. The axios instance is returned from a custom hook of it's own, but essentially, it uses interceptors for refreshing the access token using the refresh token.

Now the issue I have is that when the user has no access token/refresh token, the useSWR hook still makes consistent attempts to fetch user data. I read up about conditional fetching but that doesn't work in this case, since it's impossible to know if the user has a refresh token, since it's inaccessible from the client side (nature of how httpOnly cookies work). I found out one workaround to this could be to set another cookie from the backend that has the same cookie options (expiry etc), except that it wouldn't be httpOnly, so it could be readable by the client. However, it does feel hacky / like it could cause inconsistencies.

So the last solution I came up with is that the condition for fetching the data will be if an access token exists in memory, and on initial load, I'll have some useEffect that attempts to refresh/fetch the access token using a refresh token, whether that refresh token exists or not. And once it is retrieved, all the useSWR hooks I have that require the user to be authenticated can start fetching.

Is this the best solution for this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your session control has to be on your server side, you have 2 possibilities

**1. Use an interceptor to refresh your access token whenever you have 401 but the request is sent the first time even is the user session is not valid**

```
   axios.interceptors.response.use(
   (response) => response,
   (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
     originalRequest._retry = true;
     return refreshAccessToken().then(() => {
       originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
       return axios(originalRequest);
     });
    }

     return Promise.reject(error);
    }
   );
```

**2. The second solution is to add an endpoint to check the session validity, if it returns true (session is valid) the you can proceed to the next call** thus you call is triggered after making sure that the session is active

***And don't forget to make your route protected, you can follow this link to implement that https://www.makeuseof.com/create-protected-route-in-react/***